# Flutter - iOS fcm notification click redirect on app killed state not working

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here initial message for fcm

```dart
RemoteMessage? initialMessage = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
debugPrint('notificationKey:${initialMessage?.data[keyAction]}');
if (initialMessage != null) {
  String remoteActionKey = initialMessage.data[keyAction] ?? blankString;
  switch (remoteActionKey) {
    case _Action.like:
      //todo condition
      break;
    case _Action.connection:
      //todo condition
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Main method :

```
Future<void> main() async {
   FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
}
```

Global method:

```
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
}
```

Then we get the data like this:

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance
  .getInitialMessage().then((RemoteMessage? message) async {
    if (message != null) {
        //route
     } 
   });
```